# Printing object property in an html paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, object

I should get an output of "Peter" in the paragraph with id="para1", but somehow, this is not happening. Can someone help me out?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id=para1></p>
<script>document.getElementById('para1').innerHtml = alpha.name;</script>

<script>
var alpha = {name:"Peter",age:23,gender:"male"};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've changed the code to this, still cannot see the word "Peter" in the html screen:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p id=para1></p>
<script>
var alpha = {name:"Roshan",age:23,gender:"male"};
document.getElementById('para1').innerHtml = alpha.name;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're accessing `alpha` properties before it's even declared...

Comment: console.log(alpha) and check in console that what are the properties and respective values available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistake you have.

**First:** `<p id=para1></p>` id must have `"` like `<p id="para1"></p>`

**Second:** `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`

Check your updated code here:

```js
var alpha = {name:"Roshan",age:23,gender:"male"};
   
document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = alpha.name;
```

```html
<p id="para1"></p>
```

Comment: Yes, it ran now. The syntax of innerHTML was wrongly written as innerHtml. Thanks, for suggestion! Buddy.

Comment: @Peterson WC glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call the object before it exists. Either change your script around, or use `window.onload`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){ 
        var alpha = {name:"Roshan",age:23,gender:"male"}; 
        document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = alpha.name;
    };
</script>
```

This makes sure that the page is fully loaded before the scripts gets executed.

This is by far the best and safest solution, but if you rather leave it to "load as you go", then changing the order would (perhaps) be sufficient:

```
<p id="para1"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var alpha = {name:"Peter",age:23,gender:"male"};
    document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = alpha.name;
</script>
```

Edit:

Also, as others mentioned - it's `.innerHTML`. Javascript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Your main mistake is innerHtml instead innerHTML. But all your code is not good formatted.
Let's change your code

```
<p id="para1"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var alpha = {name:"Roshan",age:23,gender:"male"};
    document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = alpha.name;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="para1"></p>
<script>
    var alpha = {name:"Peter",age:23,gender:"male"};
    document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = alpha.name;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in innerHTML HTML should be in capital.